# Can a system call happen in a C program?

Tags: c, function, system-calls, libc

Can a system call happen in a C program?
Consider this:

```
int main()
{
    int f = open("/tmp/test.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    write(f, "hello world", 11);
    close(f);

    return 0;
}
```

In this sample code, `open`, `write`, and `close` are library functions. During my searches I conclude that they are functions not system calls.  Each of these functions (`open`, `write`, and `close`) make a system call.

**Questions**

- Are my conclusions above all correct?
- Can system calls happen in C programs?
- If system calls can happen in C programs, when do they happen? Please give an example.
- Can the use of a library function versus directly making a system call be controlled by compile options? For example, is it possible that can we compile the above program with some options so that the `write` and `read` system calls are made directly, and if we compile it with different options, it calls library functions instead?

Comment: Depending on which system you use, then yes they might be library calls. But those library functions could acts as a thin proxy for the actual system calls. Or they might do other things. Or they might not do any system calls at all. Or they might *not* be part of a library but direct "system calls". As mentioned, this really depend on your system.

Comment: how about in x86? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: In other words, the distinction between "system call" and "library function" is pretty meaningless - the mapping between "library function" and "system call" even for so-called "system calls" like `open()` and `write()` isn't direct.  In fact, `open()` is more likely to use the `openat()` system call...

Comment: can it depend on compile options?

Comment: More like *operating* system (and its "standard library") dependent.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you explain more? give an example?

Comment: On a POSIX system a function like `open` *might* be a direct system call, it might be a thin library call, or it might be a library call that does more work besides the actual system call (or even does some other system call). There are a *lot* of different POSIX systems (well, used to be anyway). On Windows it's never a system call, and probably does quite a lot more than being a direct mapping for the Windows `OpenFile` function (which is actually not really a system call itself).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### System call background

A system call, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), is a "programmatic way in which a computer program requests a service from the kernel of the operating system on which it is executed".

Another way of understanding a system call is as a [user space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) program making a request to the [operating system kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) to perform some task on behalf of the user space program. The full set of system calls provided by the kernel is analogous (in some ways) to an API provided by the kernel to user space.

As system calls are a low level interface to the kernel, correctly providing their arguments can be error prone or even dangerous. For these reasons, C library authors provide simpler and safer wrapper functions for a significant portion of a kernel's set of system calls.

These wrapper functions take a simplified argument set and then derive the appropriate values to pass on to the kernel so the system call can be executed.

#### Example

**Note**: This example is based on compiling and running a C program with `gcc` on Linux. The system calls, library functions, and output may differ on other POSIX or non-POSIX operating systems.

I will attempt to show how to see when system calls are being made with a simple example.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    write(1, "Hello world!\n", 13);
}
```

Above we have a very simple C program that writes the string `Hello world!\n` to `stdout`. If we compile and then execute this program with [`strace`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), we see the following (note the output may look different on other computers):

```
$ strace ./hello > /dev/null
execve("./hello", ["./hello"], 0x7fff083a0630 /* 58 vars */) = 0
<a bunch of output we aren't interested in>
write(1, "Hello world!\n", 13)          = 13
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

`strace` is a Linux program that intercepts and displays all system calls made by a program, as well as the arguments provided to the system calls and their return values.

We can see here that, as expected, the `write` system call was made with the expected arguments. Nothing strange yet.

Another Linux tracing program is [`ltrace`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html), which intercepts dynamic library calls made by a program, and displays their arguments and return values.

If we run the same program with `ltrace`, we see this:

```
$ ltrace ./hello > /dev/null
write(1, "Hello world!\n", 13)                                = 13
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

This tells us that the `write` library function was executed. This means that the C code first called the `write` library function, which then in turn called the `write` system call.

Suppose now that we want to explicitly make a `write` system call without calling the `write` library function. (This is inadvisable in normal use, but useful for illustration.)

Here is the new code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

int main() {
    syscall(SYS_write, 1, "Hello world!\n", 13);
}
```

Here we directly call the [`syscall`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) library function, telling it we want to execute the `write` system call.

After recompiling, here is the output of `strace`:

```
$ strace ./hello > /dev/null 
execve("./hello", ["./hello"], 0x7ffe3790a660 /* 58 vars */) = 0
<a bunch of output we aren't interested in>
write(1, "Hello world!\n", 13)          = 13
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

We can see the `write` system call is made as before as expected.

If we run `ltrace` we see the following:

```
$ ltrace ./hello > /dev/null 
syscall(1, 1, 0x560b30e4d704, 13)                             = 13
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

So the `write` library function is no longer being called, but we are still making a library function call. Now we are making a call to the `syscall` library function instead of the `write` library function.

There may be a way to directly make a system call from a user space C program without calling any library functions, and if there is a way I believe it would be very advanced.

#### Detecting when a C program makes system calls

In general, nearly every non-trivial C program makes at least one system call. This is because user space does not have direct access to kernel memory or to the computer's hardware. User space programs have indirect access to kernel memory and the hardware through system calls.

To identify if a compiled C program (or any other program on Linux) makes a system call, and to identify which system calls it makes, simply use `strace`.

#### Are there compiler options to prevent calling the library wrapper functions for system calls?

You can compile your C program (assuming you are using `gcc`) with the `-nostdlib` option. This will prevent linking the C standard library as part of producing your executable. However, then you would need to write your own code to make system calls.

Comment: you are fantastic. thank you so much

Comment: how about system() and execve()? they are functions too?

Comment: `system()` and `execve()` are both functions as well. `execve()` directly wraps the `execve` system call. `system()` is used to spawn a child process to run a command. The [Linux man page for `system()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) says it uses the `fork` and `execl` system calls to run the child process. However, there is no `system` system call.

Answer (score 1):

"In computing, a system call is a programmatic way in which a computer program requests a service from the kernel of the operating system on which it is executed. This may include hardware-related services (for example, accessing a hard disk drive), creation and execution of new processes, and communication with integral kernel services such as process scheduling. System calls provide an essential interface between a process and the operating system." - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)

The `close` system call is a system call used to close a file descriptor by the kernel. For most file systems, a program terminates access to a file in a filesystem using the close system call.

```
int close(int fd);
```

`close()` closes a file descriptor, so that it no longer refers to any file and may be reused.
so as you see, syscall is used when you need to access something in kernel space and this is possible only syscalls.